# GeoServer - use SLD as include in another SLD

Tags: gis, geoserver, geo, sld

I have a big SLD that defines many rules for line geometries. I would like to reuse this SLD in another SLD that have rules for points too. Does GeoServer supports this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SLD (and GeoServer) doesn't support this.